# Get rolling one month return in a Python series

Tags: python, shift

I have a series (A) with business days as index:

```
index          value
1990-01-03     358.76
1990-01-04     355.67
1990-01-05     352.20
1990-01-08     353.79
1990-01-09     349.62
1990-01-10     347.31
1990-01-11     348.53
1990-01-12     339.93
1990-01-15     337.00
1990-01-16     340.75
1990-01-17     337.40
1990-01-18     338.19
1990-01-19     339.15
1990-01-22     330.38
1990-01-23     331.61
1990-01-24     330.26
1990-01-25     326.08
1990-01-26     325.80
1990-01-29     325.20
1990-01-30     322.98
1990-01-31     329.08
1990-02-01     328.79
1990-02-02     330.92
1990-02-05     331.85
1990-02-06     329.66
1990-02-07     333.75
1990-02-08     332.96
1990-02-09     333.62
1990-02-12     330.08

2017-09-22    2502.22
2017-09-25    2496.66
2017-09-26    2496.84
2017-09-27    2507.04
2017-09-28    2510.06
2017-09-29    2519.36
```

i would like to have a new series with same index and monthly returns

```
new_series= pandas.Series(index=A.index)
new_series=A/A.shift(1month)-1
```

i don't like solutions like .shift(25) because is not accurate:

```
new_series=A/A.shift(25)-1
```

thanks all for replies

EDIT:
i would like this output:

```
22/01/1990  #N/A
23/01/1990  #N/A
24/01/1990  #N/A
25/01/1990  #N/A
26/01/1990  #N/A
29/01/1990  #N/A
30/01/1990  #N/A
31/01/1990  #N/A
01/02/1990  #N/A
02/02/1990  #N/A
05/02/1990  -0.057779671
06/02/1990  -0.063997729
07/02/1990  -0.056643772
08/02/1990  -0.047651736
09/02/1990  -0.039417235
12/02/1990  -0.028976554
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
idx = A.index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)
A1 = pd.Series(A.values, index=idx)
print (A1)
index
1990-02-03    358.76
1990-02-04    355.67
1990-02-05    352.20
1990-02-08    353.79
1990-02-09    349.62
1990-02-10    347.31
1990-02-11    348.53
1990-02-12    339.93
1990-02-15    337.00
1990-02-16    340.75
1990-02-17    337.40
1990-02-18    338.19
1990-02-19    339.15
1990-02-22    330.38
1990-02-23    331.61
1990-02-24    330.26
1990-02-25    326.08
1990-02-26    325.80
1990-02-28    325.20
1990-02-28    322.98
1990-02-28    329.08
1990-03-01    328.79
1990-03-02    330.92
1990-03-05    331.85
1990-03-06    329.66
1990-03-07    333.75
1990-03-08    332.96
1990-03-09    333.62
1990-03-12    330.08
dtype: float64

new_series=A/A1-1
```

```
print (new_series)

index
1990-01-03         NaN
1990-01-04         NaN
1990-01-05         NaN
1990-01-08         NaN
1990-01-09         NaN
1990-01-10         NaN
1990-01-11         NaN
1990-01-12         NaN
1990-01-15         NaN
1990-01-16         NaN
1990-01-17         NaN
1990-01-18         NaN
1990-01-19         NaN
1990-01-22         NaN
1990-01-23         NaN
1990-01-24         NaN
1990-01-25         NaN
1990-01-26         NaN
1990-01-29         NaN
1990-01-30         NaN
1990-01-31         NaN
1990-02-01         NaN
1990-02-02         NaN
1990-02-03         NaN
1990-02-04         NaN
1990-02-05   -0.057780
1990-02-06         NaN
1990-02-07         NaN
1990-02-08   -0.058877
1990-02-09   -0.045764
1990-02-10         NaN
1990-02-11         NaN
1990-02-12   -0.028977
1990-02-15         NaN
1990-02-16         NaN
1990-02-17         NaN
1990-02-18         NaN
1990-02-19         NaN
1990-02-22         NaN
1990-02-23         NaN
1990-02-24         NaN
1990-02-25         NaN
1990-02-26         NaN
1990-02-28         NaN
1990-02-28         NaN
1990-02-28         NaN
1990-03-01         NaN
1990-03-02         NaN
1990-03-05         NaN
1990-03-06         NaN
1990-03-07         NaN
1990-03-08         NaN
1990-03-09         NaN
1990-03-12         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.
i think i need something like pct_change(periods='1m') not freq. freq gives me wrong output (see other comment).

Comment: it gives me wrong output:


`new_series = A.pct_change(freq='1m') 

1990-01-12         NaN
1990-01-15         NaN
1990-01-16         NaN
1990-01-17         NaN
1990-01-18         NaN
1990-01-19         NaN
1990-01-22         NaN
1990-01-23         NaN
1990-01-24         NaN
1990-01-25         NaN
1990-01-26         NaN
1990-01-29         NaN
1990-01-30         NaN
1990-01-31   -0.085101
1990-01-31   -0.082729
1990-01-31   -0.074760
1990-01-31   -0.065645
1990-01-31   -0.069844`

Comment: Unfortunately `periods='1m'` does not exist :(

Comment: I edit answer, but shift by month is not easy, because e.g. Febrary not match with 30, 31. March and so. And if some dates missing, because weekdays, it create NaNs, because no data in previous month e. g `1990-02-06` vs `1990-01-06` what doest not exist...

Comment: there is no solution for this? i would like something like INDEX MATCH( , , 1) in excel.
the "1" gives me the previous value

Comment: I dont know. Maybe not :(

Comment: Yes, but here it is probleb, becasue days not mach.